# Hidden text in PDF (how would I view this)

Tags: pdf

So I have notes from a lecturer, where the background colour is a traditional white. He has solutions in $\LaTeX$ on the PDF (I know it's there since I can highlight it, but I can't copy it). Being a poor student, I don't have the premium version of Adobe Acrobat Reader Pro DC, so I can't copy the text.
I tried changing the background colour using SumatraPDF, however, I find that the text seems to still be invisible... The only way I found to bypass this is to view the PDF on a web browser, which allows me to copy the text.

However, I would like to know if there was a way to just change the colour of the hidden text so I can view it.

Comment: You can use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert to Markdown or another format to get the contents.

Comment: Will have a go, thanks. Is there some feature of PDF's that force the hidden text to follow the colour of the background?

Comment: Would be new to me.